# How to use python to click a button? Also, how to paste clipboard content into a textbox in a website?

Tags: python, selenium, bots

I am trying to copy information from a website and then paste it into another website which requires it. For this I need to click on 2-3 buttons in the initial website (https://ibb.co/GPjgznc) which will add the information into my clipboard and then add the relevant information into a form of another website (https://ibb.co/3mqqFNJ). Obviously, this will be much faster through a bot but, I don't know how to get started and how to write this. I am an intermediate programmer in python if that helps. Thanks and please give me any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rough code. Modify as per your use.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

#Goto First URL
driver.get(url1)

# get text
scraped_text = driver.find_element_by_id('textarea').getText() //find textbox and get text

#Goto Second URL
driver.get(url2)

# type text
text_area = driver.find_element_by_id('textarea') //find textbox
text_area.send_keys(scraped_text) //text to type

# click submit button
submit_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('x-path to the button') //copy x path of button using inspect element
submit_button.click()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for doing it for me. But, I have some questions, when you say 'text area' is that the copied x path? And does it matter if the information generated is via JS?

Comment: find_elements_by_xpath is the method used to find a dom element with xpath.

Comment: find_element_by_id is the method used to find a dom element with id.

Comment: I can't figure out how to. Please help.

Comment: To test, I need the website links.